# External Authentication Services for ASP.NET core redirect failure with Spotify auth

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@nbanzyme/setting-up-spotify-authentication-on-asp-net-core-2-2-96356a061f3c) and set up a Spotify external auth to my .NET core webapp, and it worked perfectly in a local Docker container (common reason for this error is the callback URLs not matching exactly). but when I published it to an Azure App Service (Linux) it doesn't look like it's redirecting at all and I get the following error. I suspect it has something to do with redirecting to Spotify and back, but I'm new to web api development, could someone shed some light on what I should be doing?

> INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI

I've noticed that the Spotify API responds with `http` in the callback query instead of `https` and that's the cause for this problem, is there a way to change the AddAuthentication pipe used in the sample to request a `https` callback instead?

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddSpotify(options => {
  options.ClientId = "xxxx.....";
  options.ClientSecret = "xxxx....";
  options.CallbackPath = "/callback";  
  options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = (context) =>
    {
      // Handle failed login attempts here
     return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
}; // end of spotify options
```

Answer (score 2):

If you followed the tutorial you've added `https://localhost:44377/callback` as a redirect URL to your application on https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/.
When you deploy your application to Azure App Service it runs on `https://<your-app-name>.azurewebsites.net` instead of `localhost`. In OAuth there is a security feature which enforces that OAuth tokens are only forward to whitelisted URLs. Otherwise, an attacker could forge a login URL which would give him the token at the end of the authentication process.

Your TODOs:

1. Go to https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/
2. Select your application.
3. Click on "Edit settings"
4. In the section "Redirect URIs" add your adress `https://<your-app-name>.azurewebsites.net` (replace `your-app-name`) and click add.

Now you should be able to log into your application deployed on Azure App Services. This whitelisting of redirect URLs are common to (all) OAuth implementations. The only thing that differs is how you have to edit the whitelist.

Comment: I have added both http://loaclhost:33567/callback/ and https://<your-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/callback/ as whitelisted URLs. it works for localhost, but not for the Azure setup. is that what I should be looking at? should I drop the /callback/

Comment: The url is composed of a server part ( localhost:33567 ) and the path ( `/callback` ). Make sure that you adapt the server part to where your web app is hosted. However, the path must not change compared to the value which works for localhost. So if your web app is called foo, and locally `localhost:1234/callback` works for you, your redirect URL should be `https://foo.azurewebsites.net/callback`. Don't add an additional slash at the end, as you wrote in the comment.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out. I remember it didn't work without additional slash originally but maybe because of some other mistake. will check and get back.

Comment: It didn't work. it's infuriating because it works fine in Docker. Spotify is called and the login prompt appears, upon accepting the password the callback redirect fails. this isn't a problem on the docker image, but Azure fails.

Comment: Well, when the "Login with Spotify" is called, your browser should direct you to `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?......&redirect_uri=xxxxx`. Please check this URL in your browser and especially the value after `redirect_uri` marked as `xxxxx` in my example. This `xxxxx` is the value that you should put in step 4 in my answer. (You have to do an "URL decode" on the `xxxxx` value as some character have to be encoded if they are in an URL. e.g. spaces are encoded as %20 in the URL). If you are automatically redirected try to open this URL in the private mode of your browser.

Comment: Will give it a try, how come this isn't a problem on my local Docker container?

Comment: the key thing here is the additional `/` - don't add that as @wlami suggested above